# IoC DI for multitenant DbContext with .Net Core Identity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, .net-core, inversion-of-control

I have .Net Core app and want to setup IoC/DI for DbContext with .Net Core Identity:

```
public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<User, IdentityRole<int>, int, IdentityUserClaim<int>, IdentityUserRole<int>, IdentityUserLogin<int>, IdentityRoleClaim<int>, IdentityUserToken<int>>, IDataContext
{
    private readonly string _dbName;

    public DataContext(string dbName)
    {
        this._dbName = dbName;
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Container> Containers { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Note> Notes { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Email> Emails { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionStrings.DataContext.Replace(":dbname", this._dbName));
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IDataContext
{
    DbSet<Container> Containers { get; set; }

    DbSet<Note> Notes { get; set; }

    DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    DbSet<Email> Emails { get; set; }
}
```

In `Startup.cs` I have the follwoing line:

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataContext")));
```

But that connection string doesn't contain db name.

Should I include into interface such tables as: AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles, ...?

And I want to write in `Startup.cs` something like that:

```
services.AddScoped<IDataContext, DataContext>();
```

And use interface everywhere instead the whole class.

Can I do that? And how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

When you use Entity Framework's `AddDbContext` method it will register the context in the service collection for you.

```
 services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

But you could register your interface like the following.

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IDataContext), provider => provider.GetService<DataContext>());
```

Then you can work with the interface. But the Identity Services will still use the concrete type.

---

PS: Do you know the [repository pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx)? It enables you to easely seperate the data layer from the service layer. This helps a lot for example for unit tests.

---

The problem with your `DataContext` constructor is that the dependency container doesn't know how to resolve the string in the constructor. Generally when you work with configurations in asp.net core you can use the `IOptions` type and its infrastructure.

In the startup you can add the options and configure it.

```
public class DatabaseOptions
{
    public string DbName { get; set; }
}

services.AddOptions();
services.Configure<DatabaseOptions>(options => options.DbName = "myDbName");
```

And then you can change the constuctor of your `DataContext` to the following.

```
public DataContext(IOptions<DatabaseOptions> options)
```

---

If you do not know the configuration values at the startup you could write an context type which you configure in a middleware or an action filter.

```
public class DbConfigurationContext
{
    public string DbName { get; set; }
}

public class DbConfigurationContextFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    private readonly DbConfigurationContext _dbConfiguration;

    public DbConfigurationContextFilter(DbConfigurationContext dbConfiguration)
    {
        _dbConfiguration = dbConfiguration;
    }

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        _dbConfiguration.DbName = context.HttpContext.Request.Query["DbName"];
        await next();
    }
}


services.AddTransient<DbConfigurationContext>();
services.AddTransient<DbConfigurationContextFilter>();
services.AddMvc(setup =>
{
    setup.Filters.AddService(typeof(DbConfigurationContextFilter));
})
```

And then you could resolve this `DbConfigurationContext` in your `DbContext`. Of corse you could also use an interface.

```
public DataContext(DbConfigurationContext configurationContext)
```

Comment: He has to Register that using UoW Pattern like what you said.

Comment: I have 500 error when I inserted that line into `Startup.cs` I would appreciate if you write me a link with repository pattern and example..

Comment: @A.Gladkiy I edited my post. You need both lines. And I would think about registating the DbContext as scoped.

Comment: @NtFreX Then should I comment out my line
`services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataContext")));`?

Comment: @A.Gladkiy hm no. I thought you do not have this line yet. What is the error saying? [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) is a link to an msdn page which explains the repo pattern.

Comment: @A.Gladkiy You could enable the DeveloperException page to view the details of the exception.

Comment: @NtFreX I added the following line `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` and see the same. I use Angular on client side may be it's the reason why I don't see errors.

Comment: It should work with angular. Probably it on the wrong place in the middleware. And what also helps is the vs debug diagnostigs which also shows you the execeptions.

Comment: @NtFreX InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'DataContext'.

Comment: @A.Gladkiy Can you show the constructor of `DataContext`?

Comment: @NtFreX You can see it in question body

Comment: @A.Gladkiy When the dependency container tries to resolve your `DbContext` it doesn't know how to resolve that string. The general way to inject configuration into types is by creating a configuration type and inject this into the container. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: @NtFreX I can't do that because I have multitenant app and db name I get dynamically from url

Comment: @A.Gladkiy I've updated my answer with a solution for this use case.

Comment: @NtFreX I want to use middleware for that. What changes are in `DataContext.cs`? And in `Startup.cs` should I insert only these lines

`services.AddScoped(typeof(IDataContext), provider => provider.GetService<DataContext>());`
`services.AddTransient<DbConfigurationContext>();`
and
`app.UseMiddleware<DbNameMiddleware>();`?

Comment: After I implemented your variant I have an error "Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'."

Comment: @A.Gladkiy I added the `DbContext` changes to the last example. And yes thats exactly what you need to do. I do not know why you get the new error. Sounds like a compile error.

Comment: @NtFreX May be I need to add 'AspNetUsers' etc into `IDataContext`?

Comment: @A.Gladkiy The base class `IdentityDbContext` holds the Users navigation property.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155335/discussion-between-a-gladkiy-and-ntfrex).